# is it possible to upgrade IBM Business Space iWidget environment so I can use the latest Dojo version?

Tags: dojo, widget, websphere

I have dojo 1.8.3 in my Eclipce IDE and 1.4.3_IBM (21629) in IBM universal test client for iWidget and Business Space runtime respectively. So is it possible to upgrade Business Space environment to the latest Dojo version?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the same dojo version in your iwidget as the runtime unless you want to isolate your content via iframe.